# Ubuntu 20.04 Freezing from large python script

Tags: 20.04, python, freeze

I am using python 3.8.10 for data analysis on Ubuntu 20.04. I am not using any ide, just vim and the terminal. My computer is pretty powerful: i7 with 8 cores and 32G Ram.
I have even parallelized some of the script with the multiprocessing library to reduce run time.

I have monitored my memory and swap usage through out the script and it never uses more than ~7G of ram or touches any swap memory.

Despite all of this, occasionally my machine will still freeze: Monitor becomes completely unresponsive and I'm forced to reboot. For whatever reason, I think I notice that having a few extra print statements seems to reduce the frequency of freezing but that could be confirmation bias.

Looking for any helpful debugging tips.

Response to comments:
The system usually crashes outside of the periods of multicore use, however, the 1 thread running is typically pegged at 100%.

Comment: what's your CPU usage when you freeze?

Comment: It could be a programming issue also. Parallelizing script might lead to deadlocks/livelocks that are sometimes happening but not always... also an appropriate number of threads should be started etc. Are you sure your script has not this kind of problem? How is it performing sequential? If it doesn't freeze in sequential then you might have found the problem.

Comment: Assuming your script is 100% correct is there any error when it freezes? You can check them perhaps in Logs (Super key and then "Logs")

Comment: Something in the py-baselines library was unhappy. After some tweaks on how I was implementing that library I haven't had any issues. Maybe if I get some more time I'll try to pin down what exactly in the library was causing the crash. For now I will carry on. Thank you both for your help!